# All possible multiplication of given numbers set

Tags: math, combinations

How many numbers are possible after multiplication of numbers in the given set . for example set={2,5,7} so possible numbers are 
2,5,7,2*5,2*7,5*7,2*5*7 which is 2,5,7,10,14,35,70 total 7.

Need mathematical formula to get the count which is 7 in this case.

Comment: isn't the total 7?

Comment: How are you handling duplicates? Also, this might be a better fit for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: all multiplication should be unique in case of duplicate numbers, means need only unique possible multiplication.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's group the same numbers. Let's say that each distinct number `Ai` is in the (multi-)set `Ni` times and there are `M` distinct numbers. Then the total number is following

```
 Total = [Product(i=1..M)(Ni+1)] - 1
```

You need the `- 1` because you don't count `1` as valid product of an empty subset.

For your example `7 = 2^3 - 1`

For `{2,2,5,7}`  it will be `3*2*2 - 1 = 11`

It is easy to prove such a formula: each distinct number `Ai` can be in a product any number of times from `0` to `Ni`. So it gives us `Ni+1` choices. All the choices of all the numbers are independent, thus product. And finally `- 1` for the empty set which you ignore.

Comment: @Swaroop, then your choice of the correct answer is let's say surprising.

Answer (score 0):

for `n` number of elements in the set

`number of combinations = (n!/(1! *(n-1)!)) + (n!/(2! *(n-2)!)) + .. + (n!/(n! * (n-n)!))`

Comment: There is a much simpler formula that equals your expression. But your expression (as well as the simpler one) does not handle duplicate results, which the OP seems to say in a comment should be counted only once.